# How to add an object to the end of an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have the following code

```
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
[plistArray insertObject:title atIndex:2];
```

but would like to rather add the object to the end of the array.

How can this be done, and do I need to set the last value to nil, at the moment I dont and it works fine.

Regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
[plistArray addObject:title];
```

See the [*NSMutableArray Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDEFAA).

Comment: +1 for the link to the reference documentation which for some reason is not checked before posting a question on SO

Comment: -1 for being a XXX. It would have been just as easy to paste the answer AND the link to the documentation.